# Color edges in a directed network with igraph

Tags: r, igraph, edges

I have a network in which I would like to highlight certain edges of node `A`:

- directions going out of `A` should be e.g. colored red
- directions goint to `A` should be green.
- all other edges not connected with node `A` should not be printed at all.

```
library('igraph')

my_network <- read.table(
  header=TRUE,
  sep=",",
  text="
from,to
A,B
A,C
C,D
D,A
C,A")

set.seed(1234)
my_network_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(my_network)
plot(my_network_graph,
     edge.curved= 0.2,
)
```

[image]

So far I can highlight those edges going out of `A`.

```
plot(my_network_graph,
     edge.curved= 0.2,
     edge.color = c(NA, "red")[1+ (my_network$from == "A")]
      )
```

[image]

I would like to have the edges `D -> A` and `C -> A` in blue in the same plot as with the edges `A -> B` and `A -> C` (in red).

The list of edges should not be hard-coded. Only `A` should be given and the others should be calculated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
plot(my_network_graph,
  edge.curved = 0.2,
  edge.color =with(my_network,ifelse(from %in% "A","red",ifelse(from %in% c("C","D") & to == "A","blue","grey")))
)
```

[image]

or

```
plot(my_network_graph,
  edge.curved = 0.2,
  edge.color =with(my_network,ifelse(from %in% "A","red",ifelse(to == "A","green",NA)))
)
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but is it possible to get the list of nodes from the `from`- column (i.e. `C` and `D`) automatically and not hard-coded?

Comment: @LukasCB What about the second option?